# JPA Merge "duplicate key"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, merge

I try to use the **JPA API** "`merge`" function. I am using Hibernate and Spring.

When i call `EntityManager.merge`, i get an error saying `DUPLICATE KEY`.
I create key with annotation `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

Why merge try to create an entity rather than merge the existing one ?

All my entities extends to mother one:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntityBase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    public EntityBase(){ }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public EntityBase(Integer id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Asked add method :

```
        for (Student student : students){
            studentDAO.update(student);
        }
        //update method come from here
        public Student update(Student student) {
           return em.merge(student);
        }
```

Every time I run my program i want all fields update from my list. The list provide to an `LDAP` and works fine.

Comment: why not post your PERSISTENCE code ... the code where you create your objects, and call em.merge? So people can see what lifecycle state your objects are in. Because the em.merge method is SUPPOSED to create new rows in the database under some situations ...

Comment: who knows where "students" objects came from and what lifecycle state they are in (since you don't post the originating code). Look in the LOG of your JPA provider

Comment: Do you have created the autoincrement correctly in your DB table?

Comment: Keys are auto generate by this :@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY). I create nothing, just use javax persistence.

Comment: I mean if you created the column ID of the Student table as autoincrement

Comment: It's already what i do. As i said : Student is an entity which inherited of EntityBase and my EntityBase has an autogenerate ID.

Comment: Where did this student instance come from?  Did you create a new one and just give it some values that exist in the database, or did you read it from JPA?

Comment: As i said : "The list provide to an LDAP". I create student from an internal ldap and put them on list. Student is classic object type entity with just firstname, lastname, password,... and getters setters. And i repeat (in case of) it's a child of EntityBase which is already describe just above.